# Is there any way to download _blogger_ theme and upload it to _GitHub_ pages instead of coding **css** from scratch or using **jekyll** theme?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, jekyll, github-pages, blogger

I have been trying using the **Jekyll** theme in order to migrate the **Blogger** to **GitHub pages**. 
What I found is that:

- We can only migrate blog posts using Jekyll
- There are no much themes available that can work for migration from blogger to GitHub
- It requires extensive knowledge on CSS on fine-tuning existing Jekyll according to the Blogger theme

I am looking for a way we can migrate the entire theme of the blogger to GitHub pages.
Please let me know if anyone knows the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the relevant link to answer this question. https://thatvirtualboy.com/2020/03/09/migrating-blogger-to-github.html

Comment: Link only answer is not welcome on SO. Can you explain why your link provide answer ?

Comment: *The link I provided* answers about how can we migrate to GitHub pages exporting the blogger theme. So, I found it relevant.